# ng serve is not working even if I update everything

Tags: node.js, angular

```
   $ ng serve
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\src\tsconfig.json'
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\src\tsconfig.json'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:1000:11)
        at AotPlugin._setupOptions (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:62:16)
        at new AotPlugin (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:27:14)
        at _createAotPlugin (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:55:12)
        at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:71:19)
        at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:29:37)
        at Class.run (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:43:98)
        at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (E:\Work\Angular\Basic website\Angular 4\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:114:26)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

**When I hit ng serve on cmd it's not working although its working 1st & 2nd time but its not working now.**
All things are running perfectly. eg ng --version  .. the problem is only with ng serve ..it only runs for the 1st & 2nd time..

Comment: it's weird. try to delete your node_modules and install it again

Comment: no such file or directory, stat my-first-app\src\tsconfig.json'

Answer (score 1):

try update your angular-cli global:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Then exclude the `node_modules` folder.

Change the angular-cli dev dependency version of your `package.json`, according with the `ng --version`:

[image: angular-cli dev dependency version]

Finally run `npm install` and after run `ng serve --open`.

Comment: Working but if you dont want to uninstall your angular compiler.
just go to the project and do the following:
npm install
npm cache clean
npm audit fix

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First check your folder structure..
In angular-cli 0.0.30 there's a client folder between src/ and app. So now, when you generate a project, it's src/client/app not src/app.
So, if you're upgrading the CLI for an existing project, please add that folder manually and move app inside of the new client dir.
See [a5ddd75](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/a5ddd75f3f11a2a7b267e6c242f983c3594a8765) for more information

Comment: There is no client folder between src & app

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Leonard Oliveira, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4920091/leonardo-oliveira.

If you dont want to uninstall your angular compiler.
just go to the project and do the following:
npm install
npm cache clean
npm audit fix

It should work fine.